# Strange behavior of ImageBrush Border Background in WPF

Tags: wpf, background-image, imagebrush

I have border, 2 buttons and 2 jpg files.

This is code of my first button:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\abc\Documents\t1.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; 
    bi.UriSource = uri;
    bi.EndInit();
    ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(bi)
    {
        Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill,
        AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Center,
        AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center
    };
    myBorder.Background = ib;
}
```

This is code of my second button:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\abc\Documents\t2.jpg", @"C:\Users\abc\Documents\t1.jpg", true);
}
```

What I am doing:

1. Initial state:

[image]

2. Click on button 1 (set): image `t1.jpg` is set as background of `myBorder`. That is OK.

[image]

3. Click on button 2 (change file): content of file `t1.jpg` is replaced with content of file `t2.jpg`, names remain unchanged.
4. Click on button 1 (set) again: now `myBorder` should have different background, because content of file `t1.jpg` has been replaced with content of file `t2. jpg`. **But nothing happened! Why?**

Comment: I notice that the second parameter of your `File.Copy` call does not have a '@' symbol, [In this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx) I notice the example has both paths use the '@' symbol. Could this be useful?

Comment: As a note, `C:\Users\abc\Documents\t1.jpg` is not a relative URI. Better don't set `UriKind` at all. It is hardly ever necessary.